# How to disable Windows Installer logging?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

How can I disable, or automatically remove the Windows Installer log after my program is installed?

I see that in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300 there are instructions for disabling the log with a system-wide setting, however I need to disable it on only one specific setup file.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer doesn't support this requirement.

Comment: I believe I managed to solve my problem by passing `/L* nul` to the installer via the command line. That parameter also prevented the creation of the log file in `%temp%`.

Comment: I thought you were looking for a way to set logging policy to exclude specific products.  FWIW,  MSI is still logging, it's just logging to the bit bucket.

Comment: The reason I want to disable logging is because I'm passing passwords via the command line (which shouldn't be logged anywhere).

Comment: I could still get to it by using wmic path win32_process :O

Comment: Oh. But I guess you would have to do that only while the installer is running. Won't be so much of a problem.